# Pass element in emit.port for Firefox Extension

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, firefox-developer-tools, jpm

I need to pass the element from a function to another function, but only after the web service(AJAX) call is completed.

content script(popup.js):

```
function runThis(){
 var elem = $(".mainelem");
 var objDetails = {
  element : elem
 }
 self.port.emit("runCall", objDetails);
 self.port.on("callComplete", function(response){
  $(response.element).text("New text entered.");
 });
}
```

main js(main.js):

```
main_panel.port.on("runCall", function(obj){
  main_panel.port.emit("callComplete", obj);
});
```

html file(popup.html):

```
<div class="mainelem"></div>
```

But it does not append the text. Also, if try to put console in the function for port.on("callComplete"), it consoles a value like:

```
{"0":{"query111107803796615637436":15},"context" :{ "query111107803796615637436":15},"length":1}
```

Can someone help me out on how can I pass the element ? Or if I am trying to get the element in a wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot emit DOM objects. [You can emit only serializeable values.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/port#json_serializable)

```
function runThis(){
 var elem = document.querySelector(".mainelem");
 var objDetails = {
  element : elem.textContent; // Emit string, for example.
 }
 self.port.emit("runCall", objDetails);
 self.port.on("callComplete", function(response){
  elem.textContent = "New text entered.";
 });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But what if the elements are getting created using JS, and am not sure about what classes will they have. Think of it as a complete dynamic.

Comment: @ignVinayak `function runThis(elem){`

Comment: I had to do it other way round. But thanks anyways, I invested a lot of time in trying and debugging. Got a heads up from you finally. :)